# Shell Script more complex jq select

Tags: json, shell, sh, jq

I just like to find a way to search with jq with a shellscript, let explain it better:

I have this json file:

```
   {
      "meta": {
        "limit": 200,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 2
      },
      "objects": [
        {
          "bandwidth": 768,
          "call_direction": "in",
          "call_uuid": "84e6098a-d0a9-44ed-846e-074b6d563cfb",
          "conference": "JOG1_VMR6",
          "connect_time": "2017-01-26T19:20:01.096940",
          "destination_alias": "9892@192.168.20.11",
          "display_name": "JG - Sala 2",
          "encryption": "On",
          "has_media": true,
          "id": "92dab287-0091-4d57-bdff-f37cce6c586e",
          "is_muted": false,
          "is_on_hold": false,
          "is_presentation_supported": true,
          "is_presenting": false,
          "is_streaming": false,
          "license_count": 1,
          "license_type": "port",
          "media_node": "192.168.20.11",
          "parent_id": "",
          "participant_alias": "h323:192.168.51.153",
          "protocol": "H323",
          "remote_address": "192.168.51.153",
          "remote_port": 11000,
          "resource_uri": "/api/admin/status/v1/participant/92dab287-0091-4d57-bdff-f37cce6c586e/",
          "role": "chair",
          "service_tag": "JOG1",
          "service_type": "conference",
          "signalling_node": "192.168.20.11",
          "source_alias": "h323:192.168.51.153",
          "system_location": "CUSTOMER-JG-LAN",
          "vendor": "TANDBERG (Tandberg 529)"
        },
        {
          "bandwidth": 1280,
          "call_direction": "in",
          "call_uuid": "dd60c9a2-22e0-4685-9a3d-8573e5e6cc75",
          "conference": "Sala_Teste-Turn-up",
          "connect_time": "2017-01-27T01:42:11.103894",
          "destination_alias": "5001",
          "display_name": "John",
          "encryption": "On",
          "has_media": true,
          "id": "dd60c9a2-22e0-4685-9a3d-8573e5e6cc75",
          "is_muted": false,
          "is_on_hold": false,
          "is_presentation_supported": false,
          "is_presenting": false,
          "is_streaming": false,
          "license_count": 1,
          "license_type": "port",
          "media_node": "172.24.25.106",
          "parent_id": "",
          "participant_alias": "John",
          "protocol": "WebRTC",
          "remote_address": "179.65.15.9",
          "remote_port": 62794,
          "resource_uri": "/api/admin/status/v1/participant/dd60c9a2-22e0-4685-9a3d-8573e5e6cc75/",
          "role": "chair",
          "service_tag": "JOG",
          "service_type": "conference",
          "signalling_node": "172.24.25.106",
          "source_alias": "John",
          "vendor": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I wish to find an element inside the "conference" Json TAG, when I find the Conference name I wonder how to bring "connect_time" once I had found the conference value:

Here an exemple what I mean:
conference": "JOG1_VMR6"

I wanna find what is the "connect_time" in this particular to parser it so I built this part of code bellow:

```
time=$(cat service.html 2>/dev/null | jq  '.objects[] | select(.conference=='JOG1_VMR6')' | jq  ".connect_time" |  grep -o "[^\"]*" | grep -o "[^T][0-9].*" | grep -o "[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9].")
```

But the select(.conference=='JOG1_VMR6')' is showing compile error in the shell and won't bring me the "connect_time": "2017-01-26T19:20:01.096940" so I can't parser it correct.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON file.  The list in `objects` is missing the closing `]`, and there are too many closing `}`.

Comment: Sorry Friend it was because I had copied from the file it is just a part of the file note the full file list (more than 200 objects).

Comment: Ok It were corrected now.

Comment: In the future, please try to generate a **minimal** reproducer for your problem -- as in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That said, the immediate problem is that you used the same kind of quotes inside your string passed as a `jq` script as you used to enclose it, so the inner quotes were parsed by the shell as closing the outer quotes (thus telling the shell to not apply single-quoted parsing rules to the string `JOG1_VMR6`), rather than treating those inner quotes as content to send to `jq` (which they need to be, for `jq` to treat your syntax as valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to success here is simplicity. Just one invocation of jq:

```
jq  '.objects[] | select(.conference=="JOG1_VMR6") | .connect_time'
```

All those `grep` invocations could also be greatly simplified, or eliminated altogether -- consider, for example:

```
jq -n -r '"2017-01-26T19:20:01.096940" | sub(".*T(?<t>..:..:..).*"; .t)'
19:20:01
```

or just:

```
jq -n -r '"2017-01-26T19:20:01.096940" | .[11:19]'
19:20:01
```

Comment: It Works like a charm! Thanks Peak

Comment: This is quite right, but it doesn't explain *why* the old attempt (using the same quotes within the jq script as surrounding it) failed.

Comment: I Does because it was "JOG1_VMR6" it is a full Array .

time=$(cat amazon.html 2>/dev/null | jq  '.objects[] | select(.conference=='${compare1[$i]}') | jq  .connect_time' |  grep -o "[^\"]*" | grep -o "[^T][0-9].*" | grep -o "[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9].")

Comment: Thanks Peak,
 sub(".*T(?<t>..:..:..).*"; .t) ==> You rule Regex implementation, that is great, I need a lot of improvements in my codes.

jq -n -r '"2017-01-26T19:20:01.096940" | .[11:19]' ==> Of Course Why did I think about before, it is much easier in this way.